# Android Bound Service - How To Start?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I am stuck with getting my Android Service running and would really need some help.

I started off with Vogella's Tutorial on how to bind a Service and ended up trying out pretty much every approach which came to my mind and on the web to solve my problem.
"onStart()" of my main Activity gets called and no Exception (creating Intent, "bindService()") is thrown. But, also, no Service is started (apiService == null).

I know it shouldn't be hard to get it working, but sadly I am stuck with this for over two hours already. Any kind of help, pointers, etc. is really appreciated.

**[EDIT]**
Breakpoints set in the service class don't get hit. Also, Log.d() entries won't print in Logcat.

Service extending Android.Service and implementing my own Interface:

```
public class APIService extends Service implements APICall{ 
private final IBinder binder = new APIBinder();
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
}
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return binder;
}
public class APIBinder extends Binder{
    public APIService getService(){
        return APIService.this;
    }
}
//implementation of Interface...
```

Main Activity / binding of Service:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private APIService apiService = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
 @Override
 protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, APIService.class);
    bindService(serviceIntent, apiServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
 };
@Override
protected void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    unbindService(apiServiceConnection);
}
private ServiceConnection apiServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection(){
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder binder) {
        APIBinder localBinder = (APIBinder)binder;
        apiService = localBinder.getService();
    }
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
        apiService = null;
    }
};
//click handler, etc...
```

Manifest file entry:

```
<service android:name=".APIService"/>
```

Comment: Do you receive and log cat errors? Try putting in some Log.d("TAG", "comment") calls to help understand where the break down is. For example in the on connect.
How are you determining that you are not connected?

Comment: @eliteslayer - I don't receive any logcat error. Also, my breakpoints set int the service class (at the beginning of pretty much every function) wont get hit. I assume that I am not connected, since my reference to the APIService ("apiService") instance is null.

Answer (score 2):

You should add

```
startService(serviceIntent);
```

before

```
bindService(serviceIntent, apiServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```